# QGIS on Samsung GT-N5110 - invalid Qt version

Tags: qgis, android, qt

I want to install QGIS Experimental on my Samsung GT-N5110 tablet. When opening QGIS cannot open additional libraries and there is an error message: "Invalid Qt version" and QGIS crashes. I use Android Version 4.4.2. Are there any ideas to solve this problem?